# Inserting a table in latex having 23 columns

Tags: tables

I  have to insert a table which has 23 columns and 400 rows. I tried by using method of inserting simple tablle. But when i compiled the pdf does not show some columns on the page.how can i fix it?

Comment: Please give us more information and some code. This is way too vague

Comment: _you_ have to say what you want to do, you can easily make the entire table fit into any space, but it will be too small to read. So probably you need to allow page breaks, but do you need to rotate it to get the columns to fit at a sensible font size? With no example, it is hard to offer any advice